# How do I link wxWidgets libraries to any basic wxWidgets application?

Tags: c++, dll, compilation, wxwidgets, .a

I've been swamped with wxWidgets for weeks now. However, I need some help:

When dynamically linking a Unicode, Release, Non-monolithic version of wxWidgets 3.0.0, how do I link the following libraries?

Compiler: TDM-GCC-64

IDE: Code::Blocks 13.12

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXHRH.png

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T39cZ.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using DLLs, make sure you define `WXUSINGDLL` in your project options (i.e. the compiler is ran with `-D WXUSINGDLL` flag).

Comment: I am indeed using WXUSINGDLL

Comment: Strange, because the missing symbols don't have the `_imp_` prefix in them as would be expected in this case. Please show your exact compilation and linking command lines.

Comment: Never mind, I think I did something wrong with my wxWidgets initial compilation. After using the version of wxWidgets that comes with CodeLite, everything works fine...

Comment: Well... expect for the resource compiler. Apparantly windres.exe doesn't compile the correct resource type for the correct architecture on 64-bit. Too bad...

Comment: You need to use `-F pe-i386` if you use 64 bit windres for 32 bit builds.

Comment: I tried doing this just to the resource file outside of my IDE but for some reason when I build through my IDE after doing this I cannot run the executable, it says it is not a valid Win32 application, with a 0x00000b or whatever error.